# What does iter() do to list?

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.5

I have this code:

```
a = ['animal', 'dog', 'car', 'bmw', 'color', 'blue']
a_iter = iter(a)

print(a)
print(a_iter)

print(dict(zip(a,a)))
print(dict(zip(a_iter,a_iter)))
```

and output is:

```
['animal', 'dog', 'car', 'bmw', 'color', 'blue']
<list_iterator object at 0x7f2d98b756d8>
{'dog': 'dog', 'car': 'car', 'animal': 'animal', 'color': 'color', 'blue': 'blue', 'bmw': 'bmw'}
{'car': 'bmw', 'color': 'blue', 'animal': 'dog'}
```

I do not understad, why the zip works differently with `a_iter` than `a`. What does `iter()` do, list is iterable, so why use `iter()`? Could anybody explain me this with some nice example? I googled about it but I still do not understand it.

Comment: iterators are a special type of objects, they are made to e iterate over, so they are fast and are not saved in memory, they are mainly use in `for` cycles for speed, you can always transform an iterator to a list by `list() `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`iter(l)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) returns an iterator object for `l`. Together with [`next(i)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) it can be used for iterating the elements of `l`.

The code:

```
for x in l: print(x)
```

is equivalent to this code explicitly using the iterator:

```
i = iter(l)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(i)
        print(x)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Note that an iterator can also be traversed with a for loop:

```
i = iter(l)
for x in i:
    print(x)
```

---

`zip(a,b)` consumes one element from `a`, `b` at a time.

When the argument of zip is a sequence, it will create its own iterator for it.

When the argument is an iterator, it will just consume elements from it.

When it is **the same** iterator in both arguments, each iteration of zip will consume one element of the iterator for the first argument, and one element for the second argument.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [10,20,30,40]

>>> list(zip(a, b)) # zip two lists
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 40)]

>>> list(zip(a, a)) # zip a list with itself
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]

>>> i1 = iter(a)
>>> i2 = iter(a)
>>> list(zip(i1, i2)) # same as above, but with iterators
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]

>>> i = iter(a)
>>> list(zip(i, i)) # same as above, but with the same iterator
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you for great explanation!

Answer (score 9):

`iter()` does nothing to a list; the `list` object has an `__iter__` method that `iter()` uses to produce an iterator object. That object has a reference to the original list and an index; every time you ask for the next value in the iterator, the value at the current index is retrieved and returned, and the index is incremented.

You can use the `next()` function to get the next value from an iterator:

```
>>> a = ['animal', 'dog', 'car', 'bmw', 'color', 'blue']
>>> a_iter = iter(a)
>>> next(a_iter)  # get the next value
'animal'
>>> next(a_iter)  # get the next value
'dog'
```

Notice how calling `next()` again gives you a new value. You can do so until the iterator is done:

```
>>> three_more = next(a_iter), next(a_iter), next(a_iter)
>>> next(a_iter)  # last one
'blue'
>>> next(a_iter)  # nothing left
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

List iterator objects keep hold of the original list object; changing the list object will reflect in the iterator values produced on `next()`:

```
>>> b = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> b_iter = iter(b)
>>> next(b_iter)
'foo'
>>> b[1] = 'spam'
>>> b
['foo', 'spam']
>>> next(b_iter)
'spam'
```

`zip()` asks for the next value in each of its arguments, which are assumed to be *iterables*; `zip()` calls `iter()` on them all. For iterator objects such as `a_iter`, `iter(a_iter)` returns the iterator itself (it's already an iterator, after all):

```
>>> iter(a_iter)
<list_iterator object at 0x10e7b6a20>
>>> iter(a_iter) is a_iter
True
```

Since `a_iter` will yield values from the original list, in order, that means that you get paired-up elements in a dictionary, because `zip()` has *two references to the same object*; you effectively creating `(next(a_iter), next(a_iter))` as the iterator step values for `zip()`. If you pass in two references to `a`, on the other hand, `zip()` will call `iter()` *twice*, creating *two separate iterator objects*, and each have their own index to track.

Let's look at that in detail. Note that `zip()` *also* produces an iterator object, so we can verify that calling `next()` on `zip()` in turn causes `a_iter` to step forward twice:

```
>>> a_iter = iter(a)
>>> a_iter_zip = zip(a_iter, a_iter)
>>> a_iter_zip   # a zip object is an iterator too
<zip object at 0x10e7ba8c8>
>>> next(a_iter_zip)  # get next value of a_iter, together with the next value of a_iter
('animal', 'dog')
>>> next(a_iter)  # the a-list iterator was advanced, so now we get 'car'
'car'
>>> next(a_iter_zip)  # now a_iter is at bmw, so we get bmw and color
('bmw', 'color')
```

Iterators are independent objects, they each have their own index:

```
>>> a_iter1 = iter(a)
>>> a_iter2 = iter(a)   # different iterator from a_iter1
>>> next(a_iter1), next(a_iter1)  # what zip() does
('animal', 'dog')
>>> next(a_iter2), next(a_iter2)  # iter2 is independent
('animal', 'dog')
```

So when you use `zip(a, a)`, what really happens is that `zip()` calls `iter(a)` two times, creating two new iterators, and both are used to create the output:

```
>>> a_iter1 = iter(a)
>>> a_iter2 = iter(a)
>>> a_iter_1_and_2_zip = zip(a_iter1, a_iter2)
>>> next(a_iter_1_and_2_zip)  # values from a_iter1 and a_iter2
('animal', 'animal')
>>> next(a_iter_1_and_2_zip)  # moving in lockstep
('dog', 'dog')
>>> next(a_iter1)   # moving one of these two one step along, to 'car'
'car'
>>> next(a_iter_1_and_2_zip)   # so a_iter1 is one step ahead!
('bmw', 'car')
>>> next(a_iter1)   # another extra step
'color'
>>> next(a_iter_1_and_2_zip)   # so a_iter1 is two steps ahead!
('blue', 'bmw')
```

Answer (score 1):

iter() function return a instance of iterator on which we can iterate for getting all the value one by one.It is memory efficient function because it stores only current element value.